# Angular 2 Route Params in Child Routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a route: /app/project/23/views

Each part of the path is a child of the previous part and all children are lazy loaded (not sure if the lazy loaded bit here is relevant)

```
/app           (root  component)
  /project     (child component of app, child route of app)
    /23        (route param 'projectId')
      /views   (child component of project, child route of project)
```

I'm trying to access the route parameter 'projectId' (in this case: 23)

Doing the following:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        console.log('params:', params);
}
```

Gives me an empty object for this.route.params

```
params: {}
```

However doing this:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.parent.parent.params.subscribe(params => {
        console.log('params:', params);
}
```

Gives me what I'm looking for:

```
params: Object {projectId: "23"}
```

Because it is a child route, do I have to specify this.route.**parent.parent** to get the route params of (some) parent route?

Is there any better way of getting the params from the **full** route because what happens if:

1) I change the depth of the child route and move it one more step down. Do I have to change my code now to say this.route.**parent.parent.parent**.params

2) Or say it's the 10th (generation?, sub-child?, great-great-great-grandchild?).  Do I then have to say: this.route.**parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent**.params

--- Edit: added routing config files ---

**app.routing.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'app', loadChildren: './views/private/private.module#PrivateModule'}
];
```

**private.routing.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: PrivateComponent,
  children: [            
    {path: 'project', loadChildren: './project/project.module#ProjectModule'},
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'project', pathMatch: 'full'}
 ]
```

**project.routing.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: ':projectId',
  component: ProjectComponent,
  children: [
    {path: 'views', loadChildren: './views/views.module#ViewsModule'},
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'views', pathMatch: 'full'}
  ]
```

Comment: Could you please show all your route-configs. And in which component do you want to access the `params`?

Comment: @mxii added the route-configs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the tree of the route with `pathFromRoot` property, it returns an array of `ActivatedRoutes` with all parents.

```
this.route.pathFromRoot[2].params
```

Answer (score 3):

For the reasons you mentioned, I also think that it is a poor design decision to localize route parameters. This is not how server side routing works, I'm not sure why they felt their router should be any different.

As I also cannot rely on the parameter to always be in the same path on a route, I have a more generic solution that will combine all parameters into a single Observable.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

/**
 * Merges all parameters within the routing tree into a single observable. 
 * This allows child routes to access parameters from their parents
 * @param route An activated route
 */
export function routeParams(route: ActivatedRoute): Observable<Params> {
    return Observable.combineLatest(route.pathFromRoot.map(t => t.params))
        .pipe(
            map(paramObjects => Object.assign({}, ...paramObjects))
        );
}
```

Example usage would be on if you have a route `person\1\view\details` where `1` is the `id` parameter several parents above in your routing config. If you want the id parameter in the `details` route, if you use the above code and subscribe to that observable, you will get back `{"id": "1"}`

`routeParams(this.route).subscribe(params => console.log(params)`)

Comment: This is clever solution. I do see one minor drawback that i've run into many times. In case of a route such as '/class/:id/user/:id' there is no way to distinguish which :id is which. I've started using verbose param names to avoid that but still happens from time to time

Comment: Yep, unfortunately that the nature of routing and parameters. I'm updating this post to show the helper function I created.